# No entiendo como hacer que en la segunda impresión me quite los números que se guardaron en la anterior

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, arraylist, java-util-scanner

**Estoy intentando hacer un código que haga lo siguiente:**[image]

 **Este es mi código:**

Solo llevo la parte del bucle, para pedir los números una sola vez y y hacer la operación, el problema dice que el usuario elije el numero de casos que va a ingresar.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConstanteKaprekar {
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int num2[] = new int [4];
int numas[] = new int [4];
int numde[] = new int [4];
int aux=0, restat=0,c=0;
String sumas1="", sumde1="";
String numastoS[] = new String[4];
String numdetoS[] = new String[4];

//Ingresar numero
System.out.println("Ingresa el numero");
System.out.println();

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
     num2[i] = in.nextInt();
}

while(restat!=6174){
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
     numas[i] = num2[i];
     numde[i] = num2[i];
} 
  /////// Orden ascendente
     for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
         for(int b=(i+1); b<4; b++){
             if(numas[i]>numas[b])
             {
                 aux=numas[i];
                 numas[i]=numas[b];
                 numas[b]=aux;
             }
         }
     }
     /////// Orden descendente
     for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
         for(int b=(i+1); b<4; b++){
             if(numde[i]<numde[b])
             {
                 aux=numde[i];
                 numde[i]=numde[b];
                 numde[b]=aux;
             }
         }
     }
////////// Convertir numas a String
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
     numastoS[i] = Integer.toString(numas[i]);
}
 ////////// Convertir numde a String
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
     numdetoS[i] = Integer.toString(numde[i]);
} 
////// Unir numeros de numastoS
 System.out.println();
     for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
     sumas1= sumas1+numastoS[i]; //sumas1 es el numero completo pero en string
}
////// Unir numeros de numdetoS
 System.out.println();
     for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
     sumde1= sumde1+numdetoS[i]; //sumde1 es el numero completo pero en string
}   
/// Convertir union sumas en int// Parte final ascendente
  int sumas2 = Integer.parseInt(sumas1);
System.out.println(sumas2);
/// Convertir union sumas en int// Parte final descendente 
  int sumde2 = Integer.parseInt(sumde1);
System.out.println(sumde2);

//// Imprime el resultado de la resta
restat= sumde2-sumas2;
int sep=restat;
System.out.println(restat);

///Asigna los el resultado al arreglo, digito por digito
num2[0] =sep%10;

sep = sep/10;
num2[1]=sep%10;

sep=sep/10;
num2[2]=sep%10;

sep=sep/10;
num2[3] =sep%10;
}
c++;
 }
 }
```

**El resultado que me manda es este:**

[image]

No entiendo como hacer que en la segunda impresión me quite los números de la anterior, en la parte final me aparece el orden ascendente del anterior junto con el nuevo, el orden descendente del anterior junto el nuevo y el resultado de la resta anterior junto con la nueva igual, ya no se en donde esta el error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a inicializar a cero la variable sumde1 y sumas1. Como son variables de tipo string sería con cadena vacía, no con cero.

```
sumde1=""; //Inicializo a cadena vacia antes del for
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
 sumde1= sumde1+numdetoS[i]; //sumde1 es el numero completo pero en string
}
```

Esto es con la variable sumde1, tendrías que hacerlo con sumas1 también.
En la primera iteración te lo muestra bien, porque cuando declaras sumas1 y sumde1 las inicializas con cadena vacía, pero dentro del while no vuelves a vaciar estas dos variables en ningun sitio, me parece.

Comment: Gracias por responder :), me funciono. Que bueno ya no sabia como resolverlo xP